# Des « épaules bien avalées »

Tags: sens, adjectifs, france

*La Petite Fadette*, Georges Sand;

> Ils avaient tout à fait bonne mine, de grands yeux bleus, les épaules bien avalées, le corps droit et bien planté, plus de taille et de hardiesse que tous ceux de leur âge […]

La définition du terme « avalé » laisse penser qu'il sert à décrire une qualité non enviable.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aval%C3%A9)) B.− Vieilli. [En parlant de certaines parties du corps] Qui est affaissé, qui pend. Avoir les joues, les épaules avalées. Cette chienne mettra bas bientôt, elle a le ventre fort avalé (Ac.1932).Ventre avalé. Cheval à la croupe avalée

Cependant, dans le texte tout laisse à penser que ce n'est pas le cas, en particulier l'utilisation de l'adverbe « bien ».

Comment comprendre cet adjectif dans le texte de Sand ?

Comment: Avoir les épaules bien descendues peut aussi vouloir dire qu'elles sont basses un peu comme chez un adulte et non pas étroites et saillantes comme chez d'autres enfants.

Comment: @guillaume31 J'aime bien l'idée et ce serait bien d'essayer de la motiver ; j'ai une idée similaire, pour « étendues » sur la largeur, donc larges ou carrées, mais je suis incapable d'étayer ça. Normalement c'est _tombantes_ dans l'autre sens (vers l'avant), comme le dos courbé, non ? Deux autres possibilités. La première, ce serait perçu comme un signe d'[efforts passés](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Dariolette/LqnvAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22%C3%A9paules+aval%C3%A9es%22&dq=%22%C3%A9paules+aval%C3%A9es%22&printsec=frontcover) comme celui qui a beaucoup porté des brancards...

Comment: La deuxième ce serait non pas le sens différent mais la perception différente de l'[esthétique du corps](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/L_%C3%89ducation_physique/B-6fAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22%C3%A9paules+aval%C3%A9es%22&dq=%22%C3%A9paules+aval%C3%A9es%22&printsec=frontcover), Renaissance : épaules avalées ; type moderne : épaules droites. Mais avec Sand ça ne cadre pas. Je ne suis pas capable de formuler une réponse digne de ce nom.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle oui c'est exactement ça, des épaules peuvent être avalées parce que le dos est voûté vers l'avant, de fatigue , de découragement etc. Mais l'adverbe "bien" suggère autre chose ici.